# How to detect middle 3 characters from an odd number string that is inputted using a scanner?

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm trying to return the last 3 letters of a word using the substring method but how do I return the last 3 letters of a word if the word can be any size?

My code looks like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
     String inputWord;

     inputWord = scnr.next();

     System.out.println("Enter word: " + inputWord + " Postfix: " + inputWord.substring(4,7));

  }
}
```

The reason I have a 4 and 7 in the substring method is because I have tried it with the word puzzled and it returned the last 3 letters as it was supposed to do. But if I try, for instance fish, I get an error.

P.S. Please don't bash me I'm new to coding :)

Comment: Use `inputWord.length()` and a bit of math.